# JavaHL Not Available - SVN with Eclipse 4.3 Kepler on osx 10.8.5

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, svn

I have followed some posts that asked me to install MacPorts. I did but eclipse still says that JavaHL library is not available. The MacPort I downloaded and installed is called: MacPorts-2.3.2-10.8-MountainLion.pkg

I also installed the SVNKit Client Adapter but pure Java SVNKit Library is not provided as an option.

I installed my SVN via Install New Software > http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x > and I installed the complete package

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So..I can't believe I myself have resolved all the questions I have posted on stackoverflow thus far..but I found this post on a Chinese blog:
http://blog.csdn.net/csu_wgz/article/details/21551979

They provided a very straightforward and clear steps for eclipse on osx 10.8.5

```
 1. Help --> Install New Software --> http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x 
 2. Download XCode (this is something I don't have). After install XCode, install Command Ling tool from Xcode --> Preference --> Downloads
 3. Install MacPorts from http://www.macports.org/install.php and after installation, execute udo port install subversion-javahlbindings in the terminal
```

SVN works on my lion now!